# Java Inner class shadowing external class in the same .java file

Tags: java, inner-classes, shadowing

Consider:

```
    package test;
    class Same {
        void method() {
            System.out.println("outer");
        }
    }

    public class Main {
        class Same {
            void method() {
                System.out.println("middle");
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Same().method(); // Compile time Exception: No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible
        }
    }
```

I know that the Inner class 'shadows' the outer class 'Same', thus why I'm getting compile error. I would like to know is it possible to create an instance of 'outer Same' in Main. If yes, how? Thanks.

p.s. I appreciate your answers, but, please first try the code you are suggesting. Also, I know how to change the code to make it work, I need to understand current situation without any change (like keeping the classes in different files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix with the package name (suppose the outer Same is in the test package):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new test.Same().method(); 
}
```

This will print "outer".

Answer (score 1):

You need to write

```
new Main().new Same().method();
```

In order to instantiate Same class you need an instance of the Main class. Alternative you can declare Same class as a static class

```
static class Same {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Repackage the Top Level `Same`

```
package outer;


 public class Same {
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("outer");
        }
    }
```

Then create an instance using the fully qualified name:

```
public class Main {
    class Same {
        void method() {
            System.out.println("middle");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new outer.Same().method();
    }
}
```

Or as others have mentioned avoid using the `same` name for the classes.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because the `main` method is static, you either need to make `Same` static or create a `new Main()` to have `Same()` inside.

To answer the rest of the question, see this example:

```
class Test {

    class Same {
        void inner() {

        }
    }

    class Nested {
        class Same {
            void veryInner() {

            }
        }

        void doTest() {
            new Same().veryInner();
            new Test.Same().inner();
        }
    }

     void doTest() {
         new Nested().new Same().veryInner();
         new Same().inner();
     }
}
```

You can see that the nested shadowing classes do work and that you can access them just by using the right level of nesting.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write +1. Or put Same in a seperate file called `Same.java`
I know the point is to have an inner class, but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: I don't think that in non static method it will work. 'public void main1() {new Same().method();}'. Here Same is also inner Same.

Comment: And I added an example to show you can access both levels of Same from both levels of Nested.

Answer (score 0):

```
package somePackage;

public class SO1 {

    class Same{

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new somePackage.Same(); //use qualified name
    }
}

class Same{

}
```

Use the Fully qualified name to outer `Same`, which is `somePackage.Same` and that will allow you to refer to outer `Same`

Comment: @ Matthias - of inner 'Same'. This is not an anwser to my question.

Comment: I have provided the answer, check it out.

Comment: @Narendra Pathai - yeah... edited version will work.

Answer (score 0):

A static method cannot refer non static method either you make the non static as static ie.,`static class Same {...}` or create an object of that non static method and call from static method ie.,`new Main().new Same().method();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Same {
    void method() {
        System.out.println("outer");
    }
}

public class Main {
    static class Same {
        void method() {
            System.out.println("middle");
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Same().method(); // Compile time Exception: No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible
    }
}
```

===============================================

`main` is the `static` method
you must create `static` `class` than you create `object`

Answer (score 0):

Your class is in package `test`, all you need to do is use

```
new com.test.Same().method();
```

If your classes are in the default `package`, ie. no package declaration. Then you can't access the outer `Same`.